# global name 'class' is not defined - Python

Tags: python

I defined a class called `Parser` in a file called `parser.py`, that parses a test result....

```
import sys
import re

class Parser:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def udp_parse(self, filename=""):
       # ... some code over here
```

Now, in `main.py`. I have:

```
from dbconn import *
from parser import *
import os
import subprocess

def main() 
    dbconn = Dbconn()
    parse = Parser()
    # more code here ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iperf.py", line 108, in <module>
    main()
  File "iperf.py", line 49, in main
    parse = Parser()
NameError: global name 'Parser' is not defined
```

`parser.py` is in the same directory as `dbconn.py` and `main.py`. `Dbconn()` works without any problem, but I'm not understanding why `Parser()` can't work too ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parser is an existing [python module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html). Use a different file name (not parser.py) or insert your path in sys.path before stdlibs.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'parser/directory')
from parser import *
```

Comment: changing the file name would do ?

Comment: @philippe yes, it should. as long as it doesn't share a name with another python module.